# how to do jquery animation with insertAfter and append

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have the following codes,

```
    $('.carosel-control-right').click(function() {
      $(this).blur();
      $(this).parent().find('.carosel-item').first().insertAfter($(this).parent().find('.carosel-item').last());
    });

    $('.carosel-control-left').click(function() {
      $(this).blur();
      $(this).parent().find('.carosel-item').last().insertBefore($(this).parent().find('.carosel-item').first());
    });

$('.carosel-item').hover(function(){
    var number =$(this).attr('data-slide-to');       
    $('.hover-content-display .item').css('display', 'none');
    $('.hover-content-display .item[data-slide='+ number +']').css('display', 'block');
    $('.hover-content-display').append($('div[data-slide=' + number +']'));    
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3fhL2r42/

when I clicked the left or right icon, I want it to scroll left or right, how do I do that with animation?
also I like to add some animation effect on the hover function, but not sure how to combine append and animation together.

Comment: The way you're doing this, you don't really have the option of animating. You can't animate DOM manipulation, so if you wanted a scrolling animation, your slides would need to remain static and just change horizontal position.

Comment: You should try adding/changing the CSS class... That is efficient way...